# Instantiate a class in Python

Tags: python

How can one instantiate the class `Person` only using the attributes name and age?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, middlename, lastname, age):
        self.name = name
        self.middlename = middlename 
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age
        
    new_person = Person(name = "Dave", age= 22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant try to define another args as None. for example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, middlename=None, lastname=None, age):
        self.name = name
        self.middlename = middlename 
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age
        
    new_person = Person(name="Dave", age=22)
    new_person = Person(name="Dave", middlename="va", age=24)
```

Comment: you have to put "age" in front of the default arguments or you will get an error

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide [default](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) values for the rest of the arguments. For example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, middlename="", lastname=""):
```

Answer (score 0):

set args in **init** method `middlename=None, lastname=None` as optional args